# What does 'Insert into linked table failed, RAISERROR could not locate entry for error x in sysmessages' mean?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, linked-tables

I'm asking Access 2002 to run a query like this against an SQL 2000 Server:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT (col1, col2, col3)
FROM tableB LEFT JOIN tableA ON tableA.id = tableB.id
WHERE tableA.id IS NULL;
```

But it fails and gives me the following message:

> **Microsoft Access**
>
> ODBC--insert on a linked table 'tableA' failed.
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]RAISERROR could not
>   locate entry for error 800311 in sysmessages. (#2758)

What is happening?

It may be worth it to note that tableA is a linked table whereas tableB is a table that exists only in Access..

Answer (score 0):

The message suggests that some SQL code somewhere is explicitly raising an error with ID 800311, but that error has not been added to sysmessages with sp_addmessage. I would use SQL Profiler to see exactly how the query is being executed on the server and where the error is raised. I assume you're on SQL 2000 because of the reference to sysmessages, but you should always mention the version.

Comment: I can't find any decent tutorial on how to use the SQL Profiler with these ancient technologies. Any suggestions?